# Proof that a strictly decreasing sequence of nested intervals boils down to a single point.

Tags: analysis

The **nested intervals theorem** says the following.

If a sequence of intervals $\langle I_n\rangle$ is decreasing, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$ is **not empty**.

However, I'm trying to modify the theorem, say, if the sequence is **strictly decreasing**, then $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} I_n$  should be a **single point**.

---

What I **tried**:

Let $I_n = [ a_n, b_n]$. Then $\langle a_n\rangle$ is increasing, while $\langle b_n\rangle$ is decreasing. Since $\langle a_n\rangle$ is bounded, it converges to a point, say $\alpha$. And, since $b_k$ is an upper bound $\forall k$, thus $\alpha \le b_k$.

Even if $\langle b_n\rangle$ is decreasing and bounded, I don't know how I can say $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = \alpha$.

Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: If all you want is to prove that the intersection **may** be a singleton, one example is enough. Take $a_n=-\frac1n$ and $b_n=\frac1n$, for instance. The intersection will be $\{0\}$ then.

Comment: The sequence strictly decreasing is not enough here. You need the limit of the sequence $b_n-a_n$ to be zero. Then the intersection will be one point.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I modified the expression.

Comment: @Mark Is there any counter-example?

Comment: @moreblue Consider $I_n = \left(0, 1+\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: The result that the intersection is not empty is known as "Cantor's intersection theorem", and if you are adding that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(b_n-a_n)=0$ then the result is known as "cantor's lemma".  A $\LaTeX$ tip, use \langle and \rangle to create $\langle$ and $\rangle$

Comment: I'm pretty sure Cantor's intersection theorem is what OP meant to ask, so editing the question might be necessary here

Comment: I think it's worth noting that you nearly provided your own counterexample.  If you're stuck on a step of a proof, see if you can come up with an example where that step fails.  In your case, it would be easy to manufacture two sequences as in your problem where $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ *doesn't* equal $\alpha$, and then you'd have your counterexample.  (Of course, this is just what [@JoséCarlosSantos](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2864393) does.)

Comment: (Also, a minor matter of language:  although what you meant is clear to you and to any professional mathematician, strictly speaking "$b_k$ is an upper bound $\forall k$" is nonsense; there is no such thing as "an upper bound" full stop, only "an upper bound of a set".  Thus it is better (until you are certain that you're not mentally eliding such facts) to say something like "for all $k$, $b_k$ is an upper bound of $\{a_n : n \in \mathbb Z_{> 0}\}$".)

Comment: The first theorem you state needs the intervals to be compact, otherwise $I_n=(0,1/n)$ or $I_n=[n,\infty)$ are counterexamples.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $a_n=-1-\frac1n$ and $b_n=1+\frac1n$. Then the sequence $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is strictly decreasing, but$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}[a_n,b_n]=[-1,1].$$